# Executing a procedure in Oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm trying to write a procedure that inserts paid invoices from the `paid_invoices` table into the `invoice_archive` table. Only those paid invoices that are older than or equal to 31-05-2014 should be transferred.

Here's my procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure paid_invoice_transfer as
  cursor paid is
    select *
      from paid_invoices
     where invoice_total = credit_total + payment_total
       and payment_date <= '2014-05-31';
  invoice_archive_text paid%rowtype;
begin
  for invoice_archive_text in paid loop
    dbms_output.put_line(invoice_archive_text.invoice_id);
    insert into invoice_archive values invoice_archive_text;
  end loop;
end;
/
```

I'm not sure what to execute at this point:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> execute paid_invoice_transfer(???);
```

Comment: yes it works successfully if you invoke as `execute paid_invoice_transfer;` without parentheses since that has no parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Now that you know how to execute a procedure without an argument, I would also like to point out the problems with your procedure.

It's not required to define a record variable for looping through the cursor.

```
invoice_archive_text paid%rowtype
```

Pl/SQL automatically creates it when you use it in for loop. I will go a step further and ask you to avoid loops to run `INSERT`. Just use plain `INSERT INTO target_table select * from source_table` and explicitly specify column names to be safe.

If you want to display the ids that are being inserted through `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE`, store it in a a collection and loop it separately  just for display purpose( only if you think display is needed).

I also wanted to show you how to pass  a date argument for execution so I will pass payment_date. In your procedure you are wrongly comparing it with a literal string rather than a date. It is bound to fail if `NLS_DATE_` parameters don't match with the string.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE paid_invoice_transfer ( p_payment_date DATE ) AS
     TYPE tab_inv IS TABLE OF  paid_invoices.invoice_id%type;
     t_tab tab_inv; 
BEGIN


 SELECT invoice_id BULK COLLECT INTO t_tab
          FROM paid_invoices
                  WHERE invoice_total = credit_total + payment_total 
               AND payment_date <= p_payment_date;

    FOR i IN t_tab.FIRST..t_tab.LAST LOOP
          dbms_output.put_line(t_tab(i));
     END LOOP;

INSERT INTO invoice_archive ( column1,column2,column3) select col1,col2,col3
      FROM paid_invoices
     WHERE invoice_total = credit_total + payment_total
       AND payment_date <= p_payment_date; 

END;
/

set serveroutput on
execute paid_invoice_transfer(DATE '2014-05-31' )
```